# Addition of integer input through while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I'm  trying to create a while loops where you can input as many integers as you want. The input gets summed up and printed only when I type in the number 0.

Currently I have written the following:

```
n = int(input())
sum = 0 

while n != 0:
  sum = sum + n 
print(sum)
```

When I enter in the 0 value the loop does not close and my sum is not printed.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you in advance!

I'm expecting the loop to close when I type in 0 which should give the sum of all the number entered previously.

e.g.

```
Input:
2
3
1
0


Output:

6
```

Comment: You never change `n` so `n != 0` is indefinitely `True` (unless input is `0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is that you can only input 1 number than the code is stuck in the while loop. So if you want to sum multiple inputs the input needs to be in the while loop. Try this..

```
result = 0
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        print(result)
        break
    else:
        result += n
```

Comment: Better not to shadow built-in names. (`sum`)